# the appointment.Id.UniqueID changed

Tags: exchangewebservices

I created an appointment, the appointment room is test_room1@aa.com, and I impersonate the user is jack@aa.com.

but when I FindAppointments from jack@aa.com, the ID is A. when I FindAppointments from room test_room1@aa.com. the ID is B.

Why the ID is different?

I use jack@aa.com make an appointment, and saved appointment.ID.UniqueId to database. but I need show AllBookings in system, so I have to get appointments by room. but same appointment ID is different, I can't make it relative with my database.

Answer (score 1):

The Id your referring to is the EWSId which is unique for every item in the Exchange Store. Even though its the same appointment in each mailbox it's physically a separate object in the Exchange Store so hence has a different EWSId see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123495%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx. If you working with appointment identifiers then i would suggest you use PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839502%28v=office.15%29.aspx . You can use that property to find both the meeting in any of the Attendee's calendar and also any response, invitations messages.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Can I use ICalUID? I saw they are same.

Comment: and I can't find PidLidGlobalObjectId  property of Appointment, I am using Exchange web service SDK.

Comment: You can use the ICalUid however its is not always the same you should learn how to use Extended properties as this will be more reliable see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633697(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I used Extended properties, but that appointment should be made in our application, if we get the appointments which made in Outlook, Extended properties is null. that's why I want to use ICalUID.